# Adding two values from two different activities and displaying the total in a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Have 3 Activities : 1- ItemMenu , 2- Snooker , 3- Billiards

When i press the button in the ItemMenu Activity to calculate the total of Snooker & Billiards Activity , it just gives me the total of the last activity I've been to , i need it to give me the total of the 2 Activities combined

Here is the code of Billiards Activity :

```
public class Billiards extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ebgames;
Button   bsave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_billiards);

    ebgames = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ebgames);
    bsave   = ( Button )findViewById(R.id.  bsave);

}

public void bsave (View v)
{

    Double dbgames = Double.parseDouble(ebgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcbgames = (dbgames)*0.50;

    Double btotal = (calcbgames);


    Intent btoim = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ItemMenu.class);

    btoim.putExtra("btot",btotal);

    startActivity(btoim);

}
```

Here is the code of Snooker Activity :

```
public class Snooker extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText esgames;
Button   ssave;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snooker);

    esgames = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.esgames);
    ssave   = ( Button )findViewById(R.id.  ssave);



}

public void ssave (View v)
{

    Double dsgames = Double.parseDouble(esgames.getText().toString());
    Double calcsgames = (dsgames)*1.00;

    Double stotal = (calcsgames);


    Intent stoim = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ItemMenu.class);

    stoim.putExtra("stot",stotal);

    startActivity(stoim);

}
```

And Here is the code of ItemMenu Activity :

```
public class ItemMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

Button snooker;
Button billiards;
TextView total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_menu);


    snooker             =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.              snooker  )         ;
    billiards           =       (  Button  )   findViewById        (  R.id.            billiards  )         ;


}


public void billiards (View v)
{

    Intent billiards = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Billiards.class);

    startActivity(billiards);

}

public void snooker (View v)
{

    Intent snooker = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Snooker.class);

    startActivity(snooker);

}

public void totcalc (View v)
{

    Intent gettot = getIntent();

    Double imfromb = gettot.getDoubleExtra("btot",0);
    Double imfroms = gettot.getDoubleExtra("stot",0);

    Double gtotal =  imfromb + imfroms;

    total.setText(String.valueOf(gtotal));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current version, you should get the most recent score in `onCreate()` each time `ItemMenu` starts. Then you can add it to a list or keep a running total.

Alternatively, you could start `Snooker` or `Billiards` using `startActivityForResult()`. Similar to my previous suggestion, you get the score in `onActivityResult()` and then save a list of scores, keep a running total, or whatever you wish.

For more details about returning a result from an activity, see [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and [Starting Activities and Getting Results](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Answer (score -1):

You can save `btotal` and `stotal` value in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and access it from ItemMenu  Activity.

Comment: When you are in Billiards Activity save btotal value in  SharedPreferences before going or back to other activity.Do same for the Snooker  Activity . Then in ItemMenu  Activity you can get those value by SharedPreferences